# Stop Checkbox click form other function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to stop click event of checkbox on this below button's function call

```
//Checkbox
<label id="lblsetrefmodule" for="chksetreflayout" class="lbl-disable">
    <input id="chksetreflayout" class="data_checkbox" onchange="RefLayoutDisplay();" type="checkbox" style="display:none; margin-right: 8px;" disabled="disabled">Set Reference Module Layout
</label>
//Button
 <div class="detail-view" id="detail-view-id"><a id="detailview" onclick="get_fields('DetailView')">Detail View</a></div>

get_fields(name){
    //I want to stop checkbox click for full execution of this function
    code
    //enable that click 
 }
```

Comment: You can disable the checkbox during the get_fields execution and then re-enable it. It should disable the click event for the checkbox.

Comment: @Runcorn Yes it can be done But I am already disable enable that for some conditions so It will  too complex for me to disable enable.

Comment: In that case click event will never be triggered for the checkbox as it is already on disabled state. Isn't that what you want?

Comment: Yes I tried.I think enable to checkbox become dificult for me beceause I have to check that if it is actually enable in the start then only i have to enable it in the end .But with check if label is enable  it becomes simple to do enable diasble for my work.Thanx a lot Runcorn.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can disable the checkbox while the function executed

```
get_fields(name){
    document.getElementById("chksetreflayout").disabled = true;
    code
    document.getElementById("chksetreflayout").disabled = false;
 }
```